# Run test read in bash

Tags: bash

I an trying to run this statement in bash and keep on getting errors

`test [[ "$(read -p 'Install gtodo? ' R ; echo $R)"  == "Y" ]] && (sudo apt-get install gtodo) || (echo "gtodo not installed")`

Please, what's the correct syntax?

Comment: The error presumably is "bash: test: too many arguments"?

Comment: Exactly, How do  fix it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using both `test`and `[[`

```
test "$(read -p 'Install gtodo? ' R ; echo $R)" = "Y" && (sudo apt-get install gtodo) || (echo "gtodo not installed")
```

Comment: @JohnTheBeloved if an answer fits your question, don't just thank the author, accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Either you write `test <expresion>` or `[ <expresion> ]`. In your case, I would even replace the `read` before `test`, to keep the expression short:

```
read -p 'Install gtodo? ' R; test "$R"  == "Y" && (sudo apt-get install gtodo) || (echo "gtodo not installed")
```

But it will accept only "Y" as possitive answer. If you alter it to:

```
read -p 'Install gtodo? ' R; [ "$R"  == "Y" ] || [ "$R" == "y" ] && (sudo apt-get install gtodo) || (echo "gtodo not installed")
```

It will accept both "Y" and "y" as possitive answer.